# How to make pop-up text disappear after/on click?

Tags: html, text, onclick, popup, hide

I'm kinda a beginner in HTML, so I'd like to ask your help. so I have this code:
HTML:

```
<div class="popup" onmouseover="popup()">
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Click for more</span>

<button onclick="ak12M()"> <img id="ak-12" src="ak-12.png"/>AK-12</button> 
</div>
<input type="button" id="ak12B" value="Weapon info"             
onclick="location.href='http://symthic.com/bf4-weapon-info?w=AK-12'";/>
<p id="ak-12SZ">The AK-12, formerly AK-200,<br> is an accurate and powerful 
Russian Assault Rifle.<br> It fires the 5.45x39mm WP cartridge.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.popup {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}


.popup .popuptext {
visibility: hidden;
width: 160px;
 color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 8px 0;
left:50%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 125%;
 background-color: #555;
margin-left: -80px;
}


.popup .popuptext::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #555 transparent;
}


.popup .show {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;} 
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

Script:

```
function popup() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

What I'd like to do, is that after I click on the button(the image), I'd like the pop up text to disappear
Could you please tell me how to do it?
Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example you might find interesting:

```js
function toggleInfo() {

  let text = document.getElementById("akText");
  
  if(text.style.visibility === 'hidden'){
    text.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
      text.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  

}
```

```css
.akimage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="akimage" onclick="toggleInfo()">
  click me
</div>

<span id="akText">
  AKA text,   AKA text,   AKA text,  AKA text,
</span>
```

In the example the visibility `CSS` property gets toggled in the toggleInfo function which gets called when their is clicked on our 'image' (now a div for simplification).